# Braintree Paypal checkout flow with dropin fails

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm trying to use the paypal checkout flow with the braintree dropin.
The vault flow works without issues but I'd prefer to use the checkout flow.

The client code:

```
braintree.dropin.create({
  paymentOptionPriority: paymentOptionPriority,
  authorization: client_token,
  container: '#bt-dropin',
  paypal: {
    flow: 'checkout',
    amount: 300.00,
    currency: 'EUR'
  }
}, function (createErr, instance) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
      return;
    }

    document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
      form.submit();
    });
  });
});
```

After pressing the Paypal checkout button the user gets directed to Paypal and the result is successful. The paypal payment method gets a green check mark in the dropin. When I then submit the form and the server sends the transaction request to braintree I get the following result:

```
Transaction.Status.FAILED
ProcessorResponseCode: 3000
ProcessorResponseText: Processor Network Unavailable - Try Again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a silly mistake.
My hard coded test value in the client code was not matching up with the `amount` on the server side so Paypal was authorizing a different amount than was sent to the Braintree Gateway.

Comment: Why should we use amount? the value I entered is not being used at all.

Comment: Afaik this is the amount the user will authorize you to withdraw from their paypal account when he logs in.
If the amount specified in your javascript and the amount you specify server side don't match up the transaction will fail / will not settle.